# Rotation and Velocity vectors

Tags: rotation

I've looked through the suggested, but I can't see exactly what I need.  I want to calculate the vector needed for forward motion of a rotated sprite.  At the moment I have:

```
        sprite.Rotation = 0
        sprite.Velocity = New Vector2(0, -1)
```

This is perfect, my sprite moves up my arena.  But what I need is:

```
        sprite.Rotation = RN.Next(0, 360)
        sprite.Velocity = New Vector2(??,??)
```

I know it's going to be a PI thing but that's where my brain runs out!  Could someone with a better brain please post the equation I need?

Many thank yous.

Comment: Thats simple sin/cos stuff, come on...

Comment: What's your framework? What's your language? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is basic trigonometry. Unfortunately I don't have time to explain, but here is the formulas.

```
x = speed *  sin(rotation)
y = speed * -cos(rotation)
```

This is if positive y is down and positive x is to the left, or

```
x = speed * -sin(rotation)
y = speed * -cos(rotation)
```

If positive y is down and positive x is to the right.

Please note whether your trigonometric functions take rotation to be in radians or degrees and convert acordingly.